# Passing DateTime between C# and Java?

Tags: java, c#, datetime

I have two websites, one is in C#.NET and the other is in Java.  I need to create a DateTime object in C#, serialize it, and append it to a URL that the Java site can understand.

I know that I should use UTC time to do this.  As for serializing the DateTime in C# and unserializing it in Java, what is the best "storage" format?

I am thinking I should just use something like ticks in C#, but I am not sure if Java supports that capability.

Comment: json, Strings, Date  and DateFormat

Comment: [Date class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_date.htm) in java accepts ticks as an argument in constructor. It's not the only available option however.

Comment: If you serialize it to ISO-string almost every language (including Java) should be able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert between .NET ticks (100 nanoseconds since a magic time) and Java ticks (milliseconds since another time) using the conversions in this Java class :

```
public class DateTime 
{
    static private long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;

    long ticks;

    public DateTime(long t) {
        ticks = t;
    }

    public DateTime(Date date) {
        ticks = TICKS_AT_EPOCH + 10000 * date.getTime();
    }

    public long Ticks()  { return ticks; }

    static public DateTime fromJavaMillis(long millis)
    {
        return new DateTime(TICKS_AT_EPOCH + 10000 * millis);
    }

    public Date ToDate()
    {
        return new Date((ticks-TICKS_AT_EPOCH)/10000);
    }
}
```

Note - I'm sure I probably found that somewhere on the internet ages ago - so thanks to the originator :).

Then you can just use the ticks from this to serialize - which can directly construct a .NET DateTime on the other side.